# Python Django safe increment / decrement

Tags: django, django-models

I want to build an api for a article amount management system for my store. With this I need to safely increment or decrement the amount of an article and log it with the user who executed it to the database. It should look like this:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Article(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(...)
  amount_in_store = models.IntegerField(...)
  ...

class ArticleAmountChange(models.Model):
  article = mdoels.ForeignKey(Article, ...)
  amount_change = models.IntegerField(...)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
  ...
```

But how can I guarantee the `amount_in_store` will always be the sum of all `amount_changes` for this article and still have a great performance? So I don't want to query over all `ArticleAmountChange` and sum the `amount_changes` because after some time of use there will be thousands of `ArticleAmountChanges`. Can you help me?

Comment: What db backend do you use that a simple aggregate query on one table is a problem? Thousands of records is not exactly a big number for a modern dbms.

Comment: Duplicated data (including aggregates) are often an anti-pattern. I would strongly advise against storing the `amount_in_store`. Especially since it hard to guarantee that all update/create/remove/... queries will guarantee consistency.

Comment: What Schwobaseggl and Willem say... Start with using the proper canonical solution (using your rdbms aggregation functions), do a bench on a test db with thousands of records (nb: you'll have to use the target production rdbms, not a toy like sqlite, and on a box that also reflects what you'll have on production), and you'll find out whether you really need any denormalization. And to answer your question: there's no way to garantee that a denormalized field like this will always be up to date - denormalization is a trade off.

Comment: Okay thank you a lot. I will use the sql sum value.